# Need JTable data updation concurrently based on the file creation or deletion in the particular folder

Tags: java

I need to update the j table concurrently.Scenario is we get the all file properties in the particular folder and displayed into the j table.I have developed this scenario as run time when ever we create or delete files from that particular folder it will automatically update into j table.I need not remove the file content while deleting the file in particular folder at the same time need to update new file creation. But now I am facing the problem is when ever we create one file after that any file deletion it will produces multiple row values into the j table

Edit (adding code):

```
int row = table.getRowCount(); String s = null; 
if(row<=listOfFiles.length){ 
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) { 
        s= table.getValueAt(j, 0).toString(); 
    } 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fn + " "+s); 
    if(fn.equals(s)){ 
    } else{ 
        model.addRow(new Object[] {fn,dateCreated,dateDeleted,dateDeleted,dateFormat,size,data5,permissions}); 
    }
}
```

Comment: waiting for your kind help

Comment: Kindly share your code

Comment: cant post my code because of code was too long

Comment: Paste at least the relevant code, else your question will be voted to be closed

Comment: int row = table.getRowCount();
       String s = null;
       
       
     //  if(row<=listOfFiles.length){
      
         for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            s= table.getValueAt(j, 0).toString();
           
         }
        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, fn + " "+s);
         if(fn.equals(s)){
          
         } else{
          
        model.addRow(new Object[] { fn,dateCreated,dateDeleted,dateDeleted,dateFormat,size,data5,permissions});
         
   }